# Reed switch not maintaining state

Tags: switch

I have a reed switch that connects to a relay to control lights in a closet. switch is normally closed. when the closet door is open, it turns on the light, when I close the door it TURNS OFF the light, but the light doesn't stay off, it turns back on after a few min. If I open the door again while the light is on, leave it open for a few min, then close it, the light goes off for a few minute then back on. However, if I close the door right away, it doesn't turn off the light at all. I already replaced the switch and it's behaving the same. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you change the bulbs or change the lights in any way?

Comment: Have you checked the position of the magnet that controls the switch?  Any painting lately?

Comment: I agree with Jack reed switches are activated with a magnet, move the magnet closer and when the door wiggles it will stay off.

Comment: Can you link the reed switch? What voltage is it switching?

Comment: Is the reed switch switching the light directly, or is it controlling some sort of box that then in turn switches the light?

Comment: @JPhi1618 i did change the light bulb, old one burned out, replace with an identical one.  no other change

Comment: @JACK: tried the different position,  also it's hard to get it wrong cause it has holes for the screws.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I haven't measure the voltage yet.  Don't have a multimeter  at home.  but will probably get one.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel,  it's connected to a relay. 

Switch is normally closed.  so the light is on most of the time now.

Comment: I'm not after the actual measure voltage, I am after the intended working voltage at the reed switch/relay coil package.